# DIY molecular dynamics for Xenes on crystal surfaces; where can I get applicable open-source force field parameters that I can use in my scripts?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, surfaces, forcefields, interatomic-potentials, graphene

The linked question(s) below describes a DIY project to simulate how Xenes (honeycomb nets of atoms like graphehe) behave on single crystal surfaces. Behaviors include rotation, strain, and heigh modulations (moires, bucklings, etc.) and will in the future include defects.

- [How amenable is this 2D Frenkel–Kontorova-like energy minimization problem in Python to the use of a modest PC + GPU? (Heavy reliance on indexing)](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/40634/17869)  (SciComp SE)
- [Going to try to move some of my scipy/numpy calculation to a new GPU, how to avoid disappointing results?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/40614/17869)  (SciComp SE)

The simplest implementation could just use a [Lennard-Jones potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) for Xene bond lengths, ignore bond angles and use a sinusoidal-like periodic potential for interaction with an unperturbed crystal surface as shown below.

But now I am considering [get my feet wet](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1053/201) in classical molecular dynamics proper, and starting to incorporate some open source molecular dynamics [force fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_field_(chemistry)) by using parameterizations in my script.

My guess is that open source force fields are likely to be in a form that is easy to plug in to open source MD software, and someone might comment "Why don't you just run program X instead of writing something likely to be less powerful and slower?" and the answer to that is because that's just my *[modus operandi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_operandi)*  I always try to calculate things first myself before running someone else's program for reasons of fun and insight.

**Question:** DIY molecular dynamics for Xenes on crystal surfaces; where can I get applicable open-source force field parameters that I can use in my scripts?

Here are the types of atoms I'm interested in; I certainly don't need all of them, so any place to start will already be helpful.

- Xenes of interest include honeycombs of C, Pb, Si, Ge, Sn, BN, SiC, (graphene, plumbene, silicene, germanene, stanene, 2D boron nitride and silicon carbide)...
- Crystal surfaces of interest include Pb, Au, Ag, hexagonal BN, hexagonal SiC, epitaxial graphene

Related:

- [What is the cutting edge for open-source Force-Field generation?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1412/201)
- https://openforcefield.org/
- [Are all stable Xenes (graphene-like 2D honeycomb sheets) buckled?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/123524/16035) (Chemistry SE)

---

My nascent DIY model, from [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/40634/17869) (click for larger)

[image]

Comment: What does open-source force field mean? Force field is not a code, it is a mathematical function + parameter. have you tried OpenKim?

Comment: @Greg Yes you are right, I need a better word for this. Let me try to explain what I mean. If I had a set of parameters, but there is no openly available explanation how to write an expression using those parameters exactly as they are intended to be used, I'd call that "closed" in the sense that I'd have to run someone else's code to use those parameters; I couldn't use them myself. However if they came with a complete explanation, or if their use was standardized and a reference was available, I'd call it "open".

Comment: @Greg Thanks very much for OpenKim! If I look at (just for exampe) [this parameter set](https://openkim.org/files/MO_129433059219_001/Ge_BOP_EDIP.params) I see lots of parameters, and they are likely ready to go for [any OpenKim compliant simulator](https://openkim.org/projects-using-kim/). However if I want to write a simple MD simulator myself for instructional purposes, I haven't a clue how to use them.

Comment: AFAK all algorithm in OpenKIM is published and you can read the papers. Your unfamiliarity with the field and the literature doesn’t mean it was “closed” “or secret”. Eg. you can read the EDIP papers (the Ga data should have something similar): https://openkim.org/id/EDIP__MD_506186535567_002

Comment: @Greg my "closed" would be [there is no openly available explanation how to write an expression using those parameters exactly as they are intended to be used](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8755/diy-molecular-dynamics-for-xenes-on-crystal-surfaces-where-can-i-get-applicable?noredirect=1#comment18294_8755) Since there is, then of course it isn't. However, I may have to refactor this question now. I may temporarily delete it if I can't rewrite it by tomorrow.

Comment: @Greg I've made a lot of progress and am starting to appreciate what all is available in the MD ecosystem. I'm going to limit my Python MD script to simple force fields and learn LAMMPS which seems to be able to make use of a wide range force field models, and once I'm up to speed there I'll have a better appreciation of what (if anything) I want to keep doing in Python. Thanks for your explanations!

Comment: @Greg and if I do want to continue a self-coded effort along with learning and using LAMMPS, this might be a good opportunity to start learning Julia rather than using Python's SciPy and NumPy cf. https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/503/201 (and https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/401/201 If it's useful for DFT then it's going to be useful for MD)